# naudio may be not support Conexant SmartAudio HD sound card driver? why?

Tags: naudio

i develop a chat soft by naudio that helps me solve a lot of problems.But when I used it, I found a problem.The sound card driver of my computer is Conexant SmartAudio HD.When I used naudio to record the sound, there was a lot of noise, and the voice is not clearly.I tested on another computer, the sound card of this computer is Realtek high definition audio, there is no problem and the voice is very clearly,So I guess that naudio may be not support Conexant SmartAudio HD sound card driver.Can it be solved?

Answer (score 0):

NAudio does not interact directly with your soundcard drivers. Instead it uses APIs such as WaveOut, DirectSound, WASAPI etc, to send audio to the soundcard. Its possible you're trying to use some options that aren't well supported, such as a sample rate/bit depth/channel count combination. Without knowing what output driver you're using and what sort of audio you're playing, it's hard to suggest in any more detail what the issue might be.

Comment: i'm sorry,reply later,after my analysis again,The problem is on the microphone, not the sound card, because the sound files I collected on another computer can be played on this computer, but the sound files I collected on this computer can not be played clearly, nor can they be played clearly on other computers,Is the Conexant series microphone compatible with API not well? how to solve it?

Comment: the  sample rate/bit depth/channel count combination,new WaveFormat(16000, 16, WaveIn.GetCapabilities(0).Channels);

Comment: Hi Mark Heath: I noticed this problem with the Conexant series built-in microphones recording sounds that didn't play clearly, but I don't know why. Maybe this microphone isn't compatible enough with the Windows underlying interface. Can you find a computer with the Conexant series built-in microphones to test it and see if it works well? To solve this problem in other ways, we have a product that uses naudio, and we want users to be able to use the product on this type of computer without problems.